# How to send JSON to C# webservice

Tags: c#, json, webservice-client

I have a webservice which I created in C#. It looks as follows :

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class MyService : IMyService
   {
      public InitializeResponse InitialiseConnection(InitializeRequest request)
      {
        InitializeConnectionLogic initializeConnectionLogic = new InitializeConnectionLogic();
        return initializeConnectionLogic.CreateConnection(request.Map()).Map();
      }
    }
}
```

I have a console-application which can call the service and create the object and then send it to the service.

```
PaymentBehaviorServiceClient serviceClient = new PaymentBehaviorServiceClient();
InitializeRequest initializeRequest = new InitializeRequest
    {
        SomeNumber = "869703978",
        SomeText = "FR28164"
    };
    InitializeResponse response = serviceClient.InitialiseConnection(initializeRequest);
    return response;
```

Now I would like to do the same but send the object as JSON.
Is that possible and if so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: how do you host your webservice?

Comment: This is a WCF service, right? Then you need a binding that supports JSON. See duplicate on how to configure that.

Comment: This is a WCF Service yes.